# Copy/paste data + loop through rows

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

On Sheet 1, I have a date in Column A, coordinates in Column B (latitude) and in column C (longitude).

On Sheet 2, I have a calculation, based on coordinates, that returns the sunset time per date.

When there are coordinates, I want to copy both latitude and longitude to Sheet 2 cell B3.
Then, I want to Vlookup the date for which the coordinates were copied (in Sheet 1, Column A) to copy the corresponding sunset time and paste it in Sheet 1 in the Column D (next to the longitude).

For one entry in the data set, should it look like the below example?

And how would I loop through the 34 rows of that table in Sheet 1?
It would need to do that when there is data, avoiding the empty cells.

```vb
Dim iRow&
Dim sRange$
Dim timetable As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet

'set up worksheet variables
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

' defines the table returning the sunset time
Set timetable = WS2.Range("D2:Z368")

For iRow = 12 To 45
    If Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(iRow, 45)) And Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(iRow, 46)) Then
    WS.Range("AS" & iRow & ":AT" & iRow).Copy
    WS2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
    
    sRange = "AU" & iRow
    'create formula for first cell
    WS.Range(sRange).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(AS" & iRow & "="""",AT" & iRow & "=""""),"""",VLOOKUP(AR" & iRow & ",Sheet2!D$2:Z$368,23,FALSE)),""Value missing from Sheet2 table"")"
    'remove formula
    WS.Range(sRange).Copy
    WS.Range(sRange).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Sheet 1
[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2
[image: Sheet 2]

Result of your updated code
[image: Result of your updated code]

Comment: This is multiple questions combined into one. 1. "How can I copy data from one sheet to another?" 2. "How can I use sheet values in an If Statement?" 3. "How can I loop through multiple rows of my worksheet?" 4. "How can I use VLookUp in VBA?". Each of these questions have well written answers on this site and on other sites. Take it step by step, and if you run into a specific issue, search it up or ask a question.

Comment: Please narrow the scope of this question to one specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your original macro generated code. I replaced the worksheet function with a formula inserted directly onto the sheet and then copied the formula to the other 33 cells as requested. This simplified the VBA needed. I tested it and it works.

the Excel IFERROR function displays a message if an error occurs, in this case a value missing from the table on Sheet2

```vb
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Test()
    
    Dim iRow&
    Dim sRange$
    Dim timetable As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    
    'set up worksheet variables for cleaner, more easily readable code
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set timetable = WS2.Range("D2:Z368")
    
    For iRow = 12 To 45
        If Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(iRow, 45)) And Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(iRow, 46)) Then
            WS.Range("AS" & iRow & ":AT" & iRow).Copy
            WS2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
        
        'this is your modified original line of code
        'WS.Range("AU12") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WS.Range("AR12"), timetable, 23, False)
        
        sRange = "AU" & iRow
        'create formula for first cell
        WS.Range(sRange).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(AS" & iRow & "="""",AT" & iRow & "=""""),"""",VLOOKUP(AR" & iRow & ",Sheet2!D$2:Z$368,23,FALSE)),""Value missing from Sheet2 table"")"
        'remove formula
        WS.Range(sRange).Copy
        WS.Range(sRange).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Next
    
    'copy formula to the additional 33 cells as requested
    
    'WS.Range("AU12").Copy
    'WS.Range("AU12:AU45").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus, many thanks for your answer and thank you for schooling me on how to make the code more readable. As I said, I have limited knowledge of VBA programming. Back to your answer, it's not exactly doing what I was trying to achieve. The copying/pasting and vlookup is what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to do this for each row individually (AS12:AT12 then AS13:AT13 and so on) because where there are coordinates, these may be completely different than the first ones. And consequently, the vlookup would return another time based on these.

Comment: @Tcherke I'm autistic; so sometimes I can sound like I'm schooling someone, when my intention is only to help. Apologies for any misunderstanding. I have changed the code above, hopefully according to your instructions now. Additionally I have pasted AS13:AT13 at B4 on Sheet2 and AS14:AT14 at B5 and so on. I hope this is what you intended.  I have tested the above and it works for me.

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to apologize, I meant what I said. These kind of tips will definitely help on have a clearer / cleaner code. I will test this and comeback to you. But again, many thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I've updated with 2 screenshots. Let's take 07/11 on the first printscreen for example : I am trying to get the macro to copy AS19:AT19 and paste it on Sheet2 in B3:C3 (second printscreen). This will update data in Column Z. Then it'd VLOOKUP the Sunset time (ColumnZ) for 07/11 and copy it to paste it in Sheet 1,  in AU19. And then repeat this whole process for the following row. Not sure if this is clearer, my apologies if its not.

Comment: Hi Tcherke. This is much clearer, thanks. I have updated the code above. I have tested it and it works for me.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I have tested and I end up with "Value missing from Sheet2 table" for each row where there are values. I added another screenshot in the initial post. It seems the Vlookup isn't finding the dates in column AR in column D on sheet 2. I modified the copy/paste in line B3 on Sheet 2 to the following :  `WS2.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True`

Comment: Hi Tcherke. That change won't make any difference to the code; but it's always good to try. The dates in column AR on Sheet1 are in year 2021 but the dates in column D on Sheet2 start in 2022. Do 2021 dates exist in column D on sheet2?

Comment: Hi Cyrus, it is actually crucial that we use transpose as otherwise the longitude value from column AT on sheet1 will not be pasted in cell B4 on Sheet2, thus not giving any time in Column Z. I've adapted the year on Sheet2 but still same result.

Comment: Hi Tcherke. I understand. My mistake. Can you share an image of the new Sheet2 just in case I can spot anything?

Comment: Hi Cyrus, no worries. The image of Sheet2 is the second printscreen on my question. And the key there is to update B2:B3 as the whole calculation on this sheet from ColumnE to Z is linked to the coordinates entered there. This is why the VLOOKUP should occur after pasting coordinates in B2:B3. This process should thus paste a different sunset time in cell AU19 than in AU20, as latitude and longitude are different.

Comment: Hi Tcherke. Can I see your copy of the code above then in case it's any different to the above? I updated the above with Transpose:=True etc. The code above still pulls the correct values for me.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I have updated the code in my initial post.

Comment: Thanks, Tcherke. That code still works for me so it must be a data issue. I am at a loss of how to resolve this without looking directly at your solution. My apologies.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, if you'd like, I could send you the excel file but obviously, you have given already a lot of your time into this. So in any case, I just want to thank you !

Comment: Hi Cyrus, the issue was indeed the data. The date format was not actually the same as in the other table. So obviously it wasn't finding it with the vlookup. Your code does work. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi Tcherke. Thanks very much for getting back to me. If my answer has solved your problem, then please accept it as the correct answer ? You can do so by clicking the large "V" tick at the top of my answer.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, one last question : I have copied your code to the original file and when running the macro, the file is looking for another file to update column AU. I am trying to fix this but I don't see any reference in the code to the test file that I used to test the code.

Comment: It's fine, I found the issue. I will accept your response as the correct answer. Thanks again !